# How to count unique values conditionally by group

Tags: r, data.table

I have a daily user records. Each day a user can have multiple records. I'd like to count the unique users in a rolling 3-day window. How can I achieve that?

```
set.seed(123)
dat<-data.table(day=rep(1:5,sample(6,5)))
dat$id<-sample(10,dat[,.N],replace=T)

> dat
    day id
 1:   1  1
 2:   1  6
 3:   2  9
 4:   2  6
 5:   2  5
 6:   2 10
 7:   3  5
 8:   3  7
 9:   3  6
10:   3  2
11:   3  9
12:   3  3
13:   4  1
14:   4  4
15:   4 10
16:   5  9
17:   5  7
18:   5  7
19:   5 10
20:   5  7
```

I want the result as following,i.e, for each day x, I want to count number of unique IDs in day x, x-1, and x-2.

```
sqldf('select a.day,count(distinct b.id) as user_cnt 
  from dat as a left join dat as b on a.day<=b.day+2 and a.day>=b.day group by a.day')
```

```
day user_cnt
1     2
2     5
3     8
4     9
5     9
```

Comment: Are those numbers corrrect in expected.  If the 'day' is 1, it should look for until 'day' 3 (including) and the number of unique 'ids are 5, 2, 1 and 3 i.e. 4

Comment: Or with `frollapply` `dt[, .(.(id)), day][, frollapply(seq_len(.N), n = 3, FUN = function(i) uniqueN(unlist(V1[i])), align = 'left')`

Comment: sorry should be more clear: it is backward so for day 3, look at sum from day 1 to day.

Comment: not clear if i do `dt[day %in% 1:3, uniqueN(id)]#
[1] 4`

Comment: even the code you showed doesn't give that output `sqldf('select a.day,count(distinct b.id) as user_cnt from dt as a left join dt as b on a.day<=b.day+2 and a.day>=b.day group by a.day')$user_cnt#
[1] 2 4 4 4 6`
`

Answer (score 2):

From reading your question several times and inspecting your desired output, it looks like you want an adaptive rolling "unique" function, aligned to the *right* (i.e. the *previous* n days), with a window of 3 days.

Using **datatable** should be possible, and akrun has provided a non-adaptive solution with align='left'. However, you want align='right' (the default).

```
library(data.table)

dt[, .(.(id)), day][
   , frollapply(seq_len(.N), n = 3, FUN = function(i) uniqueN(unlist(V1[i])))

[1] NA NA  8  9  9
```

Note that

```
dt[, .(.(id)), day]
   day             V1
1:   1            1,6
2:   2     9, 6, 5,10
3:   3    5,7,6,2,9,3
4:   4        1, 4,10
5:   5  9, 7, 7,10, 7
```

Unfortunately, data.table doesn't provide a partial (adaptive=TRUE) window option for the `frollapply` function, unlike the others (`frollmean` and `frollsum`).

We can try...

```
nk <- function(x, k) c(seq.int(k), rep(k, x - k))

dt[, .(.(id)), day][
    , frollapply(seq_len(.N), n = nk(.N, 3), FUN = function(i) uniqueN(unlist(V1[i])))

   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
1:  2 NA NA NA NA
2:  4  5 NA NA NA
3:  6  7  8  8  8
4:  3  9  9  9  9
5:  3  5  9  9  9
```

But we get a data.table with 5 columns with the answers lurking in the diagonal.

So I ended up using `mapply` with a user-defined function `N_unique` to count the unique values within the list of ids returned by the rolling window. We can still use partial window widths with the `nk` function defined above.

```
N_unique <- function(i, width, x){
    uniqueN(unlist(x[(i - (width - 1)):i]))
}

dt2 <- dt[, .(.(id)), day][
  , user_cnt := mapply(FUN = N_unique, i = seq_len(.N), 
                       width = nk(.N, 3), MoreArgs = list(x = V1))][, V1:=NULL]
dt2
   day user_cnt
1:   1        2
2:   2        5
3:   3        8
4:   4        9
5:   5        9
```

---

**Data**:

```
dput(dt)
structure(list(day = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), id = c(1, 6, 9, 6, 5, 
10, 5, 7, 6, 2, 9, 3, 1, 4, 10, 9, 7, 7, 10, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0bae2498>)
```

**Note**: The command to create `dt` using `set.seed` resulted in something different to what the OP provided.

Comment: I don't think this is what I need.  In your answer, dt[, uniqueN(id), day] counts unique IDs for each day. but what I want is: for day 3, I need count of IDs from day 1 to day 3, and for day 4, I need count of IDs from day 2 to day 4. however, same ID can show up at different days so I can't simply sum counts from each day.  (interestingly, I ran the sqldf command (with quotation) and it did give me answers I want).

Comment: sorry my mistake. I changed my data to have a some more variation and forgot to update the post.  I have updated the post now.  Thanks for your help that I learned a new package and function.